# NextJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, next-router

I am migrating an entire app from React to Next.js v12. I solved the majority of the problems but I'm having some trouble with routing.

I replaced useHistory with useRouter as we are not using react-router package anymore and I'm getting this final error on the page

[image]

The location should return the current URL of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `useRouter` hook to access the `router` object. `router` has a `pathname` property.

[useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter)

[router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object)

> `pathname`: String - Current route. That is the path of the page in
> `/pages`, the configured `basePath` or `locale` is not included.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

...

const router = useRouter();
// router.pathname
```